# Bootstrap image width responsiveness on smartphone

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how I can fit my image on a smartphone.

As it is now, the width of the image makes the page horizontally scrollable, which isn't ideal for smartphone use. It is supposed to stay centered, however I have no idea how.

My idea was to either make the page not scrollable(i dont know how to do this)
Or somehow crop the right side off the picture (don't know how to do this neither)

I should note that the site looks perfect on a laptop.

What do you suggest? and how can I do it?

I'm using img-responsive

**EDIT**
its working now, i was putting the img-responsive wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class tag img-responsive, but use it in the img.

If u are doing the same, copy your code, and i can try to help you.